# [Py]Spark SQL: Constrain each frame of a Window using the frame's input row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to constrain what rows in a Window frame are used by the aggregate function based on the current input row. For example, given a DataFrame `df` and a Window `w`, I want to be able to do something like:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("foo", first(col("bar").filter(...)).over(w))
```

where `.filter` would remove rows from the current Window frame based on the frame's input row.

My specific use case is as follows: Given a DataFrame `df`

```
+-----+--+--+
|group|n1|n2| 
+-----+--+--+
|    1| 1| 6|
|    1| 0| 3|
|    1| 2| 2|
|    1| 3| 5|
|    2| 0| 5|
|    2| 0| 7|
|    2| 3| 2|
|    2| 5| 9|
+-----+--+--+
```

window

```
w = Window.partitionBy("group")\
          .orderBy("n1", "n2")\
          .rowsBetween(Window.currentRow + 1, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

and some positive Long `i`, how would you find the first row (`fr`) in each input row `r`'s frame such that `r.n1` < `fr.n1`, `r.n2` < `fr.n2`, and max(`fr.n1` - `r.n1`, `fr.n2` - `r.n2`) < `i`? The value returned can be either `fr.n1` or `fr`'s row index in `df`. So, for `i` = 6, the output for the example `df` would be

```
+-----+--+--+-----+
|group|n1|n2|fr.n1|
+-----+--+--+-----+
|    1| 1| 6| null|
|    1| 0| 3|    1|
|    1| 2| 2|    3|
|    1| 3| 5| null|
|    2| 0| 5|    5|
|    2| 0| 7|    5|
|    2| 3| 2| null|
|    2| 5| 9| null|
+-----+--+--+-----+
```

I've been studying the Spark API and looking at examples of [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window$), [first](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@first(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,ignoreNulls:Boolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), and [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@when(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), but I can't seem to piece it together. Is this even possible with Window and aggregate functions or am I completely off the mark?

Comment: Can you please explain it by some example what you really wanted to do the problem given now is not clear to me.

Comment: if `|    2| 3| 2|    5|` is true then how come `|    1| 2| 2|    3|` is true? and vice versa. they contradict each other. please review your final df.

Comment: Oops! I updated the original example solution to be correct. I also added an example to the general description at the beginning to hopefully make things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with just window functions and aggregations, you'll need a self join:

For the join:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([[1, 1, 6],[1, 0, 3],[1, 2, 2],[1, 3, 5],[2, 0, 5],[2, 0, 7],[2, 3, 2],[2, 5, 9]]).toDF(["group","n1","n2"])

import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df_r = df.select([df[c].alias("r_" + c) for c in df.columns])
df_join = df_r\
    .join(df, (df_r.r_group == df.group) 
        & (df_r.r_n1 < df.n1) 
        & (df_r.r_n2 < df.n2) 
        & (psf.greatest(df.n1 - df_r.r_n1, df.n2 - df_r.r_n2) < i), "leftouter")\
    .drop("group")
```

Now we can apply the window function to only keep the first row:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("r_group", "r_n1", "r_n2").orderBy("n1", "n2")
res = df_join\
    .withColumn("rn", psf.row_number().over(w))\
    .filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")

    +-------+----+----+----+----+
    |r_group|r_n1|r_n2|  n1|  n2|
    +-------+----+----+----+----+
    |      1|   0|   3|   1|   6|
    |      1|   1|   6|null|null|
    |      1|   2|   2|   3|   5|
    |      1|   3|   5|null|null|
    |      2|   0|   5|   5|   9|
    |      2|   0|   7|   5|   9|
    |      2|   3|   2|null|null|
    |      2|   5|   9|null|null|
    +-------+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense that it would require a join since that is effectively what filtering Window frame would be doing, at least in my specific case.